# onmouseenter/onmouseleave animations apply won't work

Tags: animation

I've been trying hard for the few past hours, but I can't make it work.
My objective is to put an animation on *element1*'s ::before and another one on *element1*. I tried the simple CSS trick with the ::before and :hover thingy.. but it won't work.

HTML
`<div id="fc3"><div class="f_bb">Hover this</div>
<div class="f_bloc">This should appear with an animation</div></div>`

CSS
/can't put it here without bugging it, dunno why/

JS
/same/

https://jsfiddle.net/5Lf76r7h/

Any idea ?
Thanks. :)

**UPDATE**
Full CSS attempt : https://jsfiddle.net/5Lf76r7h/3/
**UPDATE 2**
https://jsfiddle.net/5Lf76r7h/4/

Comment: Poor use of hover for one. Although, a horrible and incomplete example, I did a tiny [update](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lf76r7h/2/).

Comment: Congrats PHPGlue, you're poorly mocking me and your "update" doesn't work as expected. Next time, don't even bother replying. Thanks :)

Comment: More-or-less working version, simply by adding another div and modifying some elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/5Lf76r7h/4/

Solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used jQuery animate with mouseenter and mouseleave to achieve the same. Please see this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/2f41k6m5/

Here is the code for your design:

```
<div id="fc3">
  <div class="f_bb">Hover this
   <div class="progress" style="border:1px blue solid;width:10px;height:5px;background-color:yellow;display:none">

   </div>
   <div class="f_bloc" style="display:none">This should appear with an animation</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

In case you need more on animations: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. :)